# Поиск повторяющихся чисел

Tags: массивы, winforms, числа, textbox, повторы

Есть массив текстбоксов tb, в каждом из них есть, допустим, по 5 не повторяющихся чисел (не повторяющихся только для каждого бокса, а не для всех). Нужно по нажатию кнопки подсчитать во всех боксах САМУЮ ЧАСТО повторяющуюся, допустим, тройку чисел, вывести эти числа, например, в один лэйбл, а во втором лэйбле показать сколько раз эта тройка чисел повторяется, а если нету ничего, то вывести 0. Приведу пример для наглядности. Пять текстбоксов, в каждом введено по пять чисел, через пробел: 1 2 3 4 5, 1 2 3 6 7, 1 2 3 8 9, 15 16 17 18 19, 15 16 17 20 21. Здесь две повторяющиеся тройки чисел 1-2-3 и 15-16-17, но 1-2-3 выпадает чаще, чем другая, точнее 3 раза. Старался попроще привести пример. Понимаю, что задачка сложная, но надеюсь, что поможете.
С кодом мне помогли, но он не работает. Вот код:

```
var arrays = new List<int[]>();
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5});
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 1,2,3,6,7 });
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 1,2,3,8,9 });
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 15,16,17,18,19 });
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 15,16,17,20,21 });

        //create dictionary of fragments создать словарь фрагментов
        var count = new Dictionary<Fragment, int>();

        //enumerate all triples перечислить все тройки
        foreach(var arr in arrays)
        for(int i=0;i<arr.Length - 3;i++)
        {
            //create fragment создать фрагмент
            var f = new Fragment(arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2]);
            //get and set count of same fragments получать и               устанавливать подсчет одинаковых фрагментов
            var c = 0;
            count.TryGetValue(f, out c);
            count[f] = c + 1;
        }
        //find max count найти максимальное количество
        var best = count.OrderByDescending(p => p.Value).First();

        //most frequently чаще всего
        Console.WriteLine("Тройка чисел: {0} Повторений: {1}", best.Key, best.Value);
```

....

```
class Fragment
{
    private int[] items;

    public Fragment(params int[] items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var res = items[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            res ^= items[i];

        return res;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = (Fragment)obj;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            if (items[i] != other.items[i])
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(",", items.Select(i=>i.ToString()).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Сначала консоль выдала правильно - тройки с числами 1 2 3 и повторений 3. Но потом я поменял числа на другие:

```
var arrays = new List<int[]>();
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 1, 10, 15, 20, 41 });
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 1, 9, 15, 14, 73 });
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 2, 1, 3, 15, 41 });
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 66, 15, 41, 55, 1 });
        arrays.Add(new int[] { 56, 15, 73, 4, 11 });
```

Здесь только одна тройка чисел, которая повторяется в этих пяти массивах - 1, 15, 41 и она повторяется 3 раза, это визуально можно проверить. Консоль мне выдала результат:

```
Тройка чисел: 1, 10, 15 Повторений: 1
```

Этот код не работает, вообще (((. Похоже он может сравнивать только первые три числа в каждом массиве. Подскажите, что не так в этом коде. Хотя, мне нужен код для Windows Forms, а не для консоли. Я вообще не вижу смысла работать с консолью, постоянно вводить кучу массивов и т.д. Проще сделать массив Textbox-ов, по нажатию кнопки перебрать все числа в боксах и результаты вывести в текст лейблов.

Answer (score 2):

Код для кнопки:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Словарь с повторами цифр
    Dictionary<int, Repeat> repeats = new Dictionary<int, Repeat>();

    bool isRepeat = false;

    // Находим количество повторов каждой цифры во всех TextBox-ах
    foreach (TextBox tb in Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(t => t.Enabled))
    {
        tb.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
        {
            // Разделитель "пробел"
            string[] digits = tb.Text.Split(' ');

            foreach (int digit in digits.Select(int.Parse))
            {
                Repeat repeat = new Repeat { RepeatControl = new List<TextBox>() };

                if (repeats.ContainsKey(digit))
                {
                    repeat = repeats[digit];
                    isRepeat = true;
                }

                // Количество повторений цифры
                repeat.RepeatCount += 1;
                // Список TextBox полей, в которых она повторяется
                repeat.RepeatControl.Add(tb);
                repeats[digit] = repeat;
            } 
        }
    }

    if (!isRepeat)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Нет повторяющихся чисел!");
        return;
    }

    Dictionary<int[], Triple> triplets = new Dictionary<int[], Triple>();

    var repeatsArray = repeats.ToArray();

    // Перебираем все возможные комбинации троек чисел
    for (int d1 = 0; d1 < repeatsArray.Length - 2; d1++)
    {
        for (int d2 = d1 + 1; d2 < repeatsArray.Length - 1; d2++)
        {
            for (int d3 = d2 + 1; d3 < repeatsArray.Length; d3++)
            {
                var dig1 = repeatsArray[d1];
                var dig2 = repeatsArray[d2];
                var dig3 = repeatsArray[d3];

                // Находим пересечения всех массивов TextBox у данной тройки чисел
                var tbControls =
                            ((dig1.Value.RepeatControl.Intersect(dig2.Value.RepeatControl)).Intersect(
                                dig3.Value.RepeatControl)).ToArray();

                // Количество TextBox полей, в которых присутствуют все три числа
                int tbControlsCount = tbControls.Length;

                // Массив с тройкой чисел
                int[] triplet = {dig1.Key, dig2.Key, dig3.Key};

                Triple triple = new Triple()
                {
                    // Сколько раз встречается тройка этих чисел
                    TripleCount = tbControlsCount,
                    // И в каких TextBox-ах
                    TripleControls = tbControls
                };

                if (tbControlsCount > 0)
                {
                    triplets.Add(triplet, triple);
                }  
            }
        }
    }

    if (triplets.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"Нет повторяющихся комбинаций чисел!");
        return;
    }

    // Сортируем получившуюся коллекцию по убыванию количества троек чисел и берем первый элемент с наибольшим значением
    var firstTriplet = triplets.OrderByDescending(v => v.Value.TripleCount).First();

    // Количество повторений тройки чисел
    label2.Text = firstTriplet.Value.TripleCount.ToString();

    // Для красоты вывода сортируем тройку чисел по возрастанию
    var tDigits = firstTriplet.Key;
    Array.Sort(tDigits);
    label4.Text = string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", tDigits[0], tDigits[1], tDigits[2]);

    // Подсвечиваем поля где присутствуют тройки чисел
    foreach (TextBox tb in firstTriplet.Value.TripleControls)
    {
        tb.BackColor = Color.CadetBlue;
    }
}
```

Вспомогательные классы:

```
public struct Repeat
{
    public int RepeatCount;
    public List<TextBox> RepeatControl;
}

public struct Triple
{
    public int TripleCount;
    public TextBox[] TripleControls;
}
```

Результаты:

[image: Результат1]

[image: Результат2]